# Converting letters in words to their corresponding number, then adding them together

Tags: java, string

I have the following code as part of a star wars name generator.

The only thing I can't figure out how to do is add a force number, which requires converting the star wars name to its numbered counterpart (A=1, B=2...Z=26, etc.), and then adding those numbers together into one final number (force number).

I've commented the part out of what I believe to get the force number, but it keeps generating an error.

Also, this letter-to-number conversion code I got is from another thread, and it's not the most efficient way to do the task.

Thanks for any help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class starWarsName {
private static final Scanner INPUT = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String args[]) {

out.println("Star Wars name and force # Generator");
String firstName = promptString("State your first name: ");
String lastName = promptString("State your last name: ");
String maiden = promptString("Enter your mother's maiden name: "); 
String city = promptString("Enter the city/town in which you were born: ");

while(lastName.length() < 3)
  lastName += lastName;
while(firstName.length() < 2)
  firstName += firstName;
while(maiden.length() < 2)
  maiden += maiden;
while(city.length() < 3)
  city += city;

String swFirstName = (lastName.substring(0,3) + firstName.substring(0,2)).toUpperCase();
String swLastName = (maiden.substring(0,2) + city.substring(0,3)).toUpperCase();


//*
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

    final Map<Character, Integer> map;
    final String str = "forceNum = ";

    map = new HashMap<>();  

    map.put('a', 1); map.put('b', 2); map.put('c', 3); map.put('d', 4); map.put('e', 5); map.put('f', 6); map.put('g', 7); map.put('h', 8); map.put('i', 9); map.put('j', 10); map.put('k', 11); map.put('l', 12); map.put('m', 13); map.put('n', 14); map.put('o', 15); map.put('p', 16); map.put('q', 17); map.put('r', 18); map.put('s', 19); map.put('t', 20); map.put('u', 21); map.put('v', 22); map.put('w', 23); map.put('x', 24); map.put('y', 25); map.put('z', 26);

    for(final char c : str.toCharArray())
    {
        final Integer val;

        val = map.get(c);

        if(val == null)
        {   

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print(val + " ");
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
}
}

//*


out.println("Your Star Wars name is " + swFirstName + " " + swLastName + " with a force # of " + forceNum);
}

private static String promptString(String prompt) {
out.print(prompt);
return INPUT.nextLine().trim();
}
}
```

Comment: You can use the value of each character as a `char` type.

Answer (score 0):

Your "force name" will be a `string`, which is made up of `chars`.  Each `char` has an integer `ASCII` value (`'A' = 65, 'B' = 66, 'a' = 97, 'z' = 122` for example).  You can use the values of `'A'` and `'a'` as "starting points" to assign alphabet numbers to each letter.

To wit, the letter 'A' would be `65 - 65 + 1 = 1`.  Similarly, the letter 'B' (`66 - 65 + 1 = 2`), the letter 'a' (`97 - 97 + 1 = 1`), and the letter 'z' (`122 - 97 + 1 = 26`).

```
String name = "First Middle Last";  // this implementation ignores spaces
int sum = 0;                        // store the accumulating force number

for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); ++i) {     // iterate over name, one letter at a time
    int letter = name.charAt(i);
    if (letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z') {        
        sum += letter - 'A' + 1;              // capital letters use 'A' as starting point
    } else if (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z') {
        sum += letter - 'a' + 1;              // little letters use 'a' as starting point
    }
}

System.out.println(sum);  // verify sum is 72 + 47 + 52 = 171
```